# Facebook OAuth error 4: API_EC_TOO_MANY_CALLS - Application request limit reached

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Sometimes I get OAuth error number 4 when my application sends requests for method `get:album/photos` or `get:user/albums`

This error code stands for `API_EC_TOO_MANY_CALLS` - *Application request limit reached*
but what is the base for this limit? there is a general api request limit (100 million API requests per day) but this limit is far away in my case.

So does anybody know how many is to many for this request? Is it based on a number of requests in a special period of time or a limit of maximum requests per second?

we tried different options but it's very difficult without having exact information what the real reason is...

Comment: How many are you making? I think the limit is about 600 per 600 seconds per access token or thereabouts

Comment: there is also a 600 limit per 600 seconds, that's true. I saw this problem at another place (fetching the stream), but in this case i received the error message FQL_EC_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED so I'm not sure if this has really the same reason?

Comment: I request all photos of all albums of my friends, so this are a few thousand requests

Comment: Could it be that my requests are too fast? We send 30-50 requests per second for fetching all photos very fast

Comment: I think that the problem is not the number of requests per second per APP, the problem should be the number of requests per second per AccessToken... Otherwise APPs with thousands of users will get in trouble easily.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried batch calls? I've run into this, along iwth another caching error, and tuned my calls accordingly. I woudln't base it on a static value but rather on the return error. Facebook changes their settings *all the time*.